# FacetGrid Data Label in Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I've got the following dummy data in a CSV file:

```
Player,Month,Score
One,Jan,500
One,Feb,625
One,Mar,700
Two,Jan,300
Two,Feb,275
Two,Mar,1000
Three,Jan,600
Three,Feb,900
Three,Mar,1200
```

And have produced a FacetGrid via Seaborn with the following code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="Player",col="Month", margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.barplot, "Month", "Score")
```

Which looks like:

[image]

However, notice the x-axis label on each chart is "Mar" (at the bottom), which is the last month in the data set for each Player.  Why is that?  How do I change or remove that label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `factorplot`, which takes care of some important bookkeeping about which values need to appear in each facet:

```
sns.factorplot(x="Month", y="Score",
               row="Player", col="Month", data=df,
               margin_titles=True, kind="bar")
```

[image]

Comment: Wow.  That was easy.  Much appreciated.